# Free DVD Burning Options but for DVD Players not data

Tags: windows-7, dvd, media, video-conversion, dvd-burning

I used to use ConvertXtoDVD which was simple and awesome got the job done. But are there any good free options that allow you to burn a DVD video to a DVD that can be played in a player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A site you should bookmark is [VideoHelp.com](http://www.videohelp.com/) because not only does it have tons of tutorials for doing video burning/encoding/ripping tasks, but the tutorials are almost all for using different free software packages.

Now, when you say DVD video to DVD... do you mean VOB files to DVD?  Or do you mean DVD compliant Mpeg files?  Or do you mean taking AVI files and burning them to DVD for stand-alone players?  Because they have tutorials with links to the relevant software for all that and more.  For example [Here is a list of tutorials for burning AVIs to DVD](http://www.videohelp.com/guides?searchtext=&tools=&madeby=&formatconversionselect=AVI%20to%20DVD&howtoselect=;&orderby=Date&listall=1&hits=25&archive=0&search=Search%20or%20List%20Guides).

So, start with the "Convert" link, and choose the file type you want to burn to DVD, and read a few tutorials... and download the free software choices.

Comment: avi,mpeg,wmv ect... convertxtodvd took just about every format and when you placed dvd in a dvdplayer it would automatically play it.

Comment: and convertxtodvd is one of the recommended programs at VideoHelp.com.  I'm not in any way saying it isn't a good program for what you want to do.  Just giving you a website that can provide even more software to do these kinds of tasks.